# Логика построения сетевого приложения и работа с socketserver

Tags: python, многопоточность, сеть

Доброго времени суток.

**Кратко**: Как обеспечить связь между двумя пользователями программы с типом подключения клиент-клиент?

**Подробно**:

Возникла идея получить и сразу же применить знания в области сетей и многопоточности на Python. Предполагалось написать несложную программу, "исполняемый файл" которой будет одинаковым у обеих пользователей.

Познакомился с socket-ами. Написал (скопировал) примеры с первого сайта. Насколько хватило мозгов, понял, что в сокетах всё делится на "сервер" и "клиент", причём передавать и принимать данные может как первый, так и второй.

Хорошо, сказал я себе. Пускай в приложении будет кнопка "создать сервер" и "подключиться к серверу". В первом случае будет запускаться "сервер", во втором - клиент (логично).

[image: Интерфейс]

Проблемы начались, когда дошло дело до  кода. Ещё на этапе изучения информации, я понял, что всё общение с сетью нужно выносить в отдельные поток. Значит, в программе у меня должны быть "*ServerThread*" и "*ClientThread*", так как назначения (ровно как и код) у них разные. До этого момента было всё более-менее хорошо, и даже получилось получить подтверждение, что потоки работают как надо, и программы "слышат" друг друга.

*Не очень информативно, но всё же (слева "сервер", справа "клиент"):*
[image: Результат подключения сервера и клиента]

И вот самое главное - процесс отправления информации туда-сюда, вызывает у меня судорожное недоумение. Моя идея: так как информация может отсылаться с обоих сторон, значит, обе стороны должны постоянно (с каким-то промежутком) опрашивать сокет (или просто ждать из него информации). Супер. Значит, внутри каждого такого потока должен быть ПОДпоток?! Или как это должно быть устроено?

На данный момент я вижу пару решений:

1. Сохранять сокет. Что я имею под этим ввиду: возможно, connection, который возвращает сервер, можно хранить вне потока? И то же самое делать и с socket клиента? Тогда потоков всё-равно остаётся два, но уже *других* - направленных на получение/отправку информации.
   *О каких connection и socket я веду речь:* [image: Картинка с коннекшионом и сокетом]
   Но можно ли такое делать? Нет, мне не сложно попробовать, но это будет велосипед, ведь правда?
2. Сделать сервер отдельной программой. Ну, такой вариант будет рассматриваться мной в последнюю очередь. Всё же идею изначальную хочется реализовать именно описанным выше образом.

**Суммируя всё вышесказанное**: прошу помочь с спагетти-идеями или хотя бы тыкнуть носом туда, где лучше почитать про реализацию подобной штуки.

Спасибо.

---

По совету **@eri** слегка переработал идею: оба приложения запускают севера в отдельном потоке на "прослушивание", а отправку делают с помощью UDP без потоков. Таким образом под кнопкой "Создать сервер" теперь находится:

```py
class Programm:
    ...
    def create_server(self):
        HOST, PORT = "localhost", 9999

        with socketserver.UDPServer((HOST, PORT), MyUDPHandler) as server:
            self.server_thread = threading.Thread(target=server.serve_forever)
            # self.server_thread.start()  # Смотри ниже
```

, где *MyUDPHandler*:

```py
class MyUDPHandler(socketserver.BaseRequestHandler):
    def handle(self):
        data = self.request[0].decode()
        print("{} wrote:".format(self.client_address[0]))
        print(data)
```

Производится попытка отправки сообщения на данный сервер из **этой же** программы:

```py
class Programm:
    ...
    def connect_to_server(self):
        # Пока что просто пытаемся отправить data
        HOST, PORT = "localhost", 9999
        data = "Wow, it's data!"
        sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
        sock.sendto(data.encode(), (HOST, PORT))
        print("Sent:     {}".format(data))
```

В идеале я должен видеть в консоли две строки:

```
(1) Sent:     Wow, it's data!  # Информация отправленная клиентом
(2) "Wow, it's data!"          # Информация принятая сервером
```

Тем не менее, этого не происходит. Появляется лишь (1), а в метод *handle* выполнение программы и вовсе не заходит.

Я подумал, может, поток "инициализируется", но при это не запускается? Хорошо, добавил строку `self.server_thread.start()` в метод *create_server* *(место помещения этой строчки смотри в коде выше)*. Теперь программа совершенно не хочет запускаться, заявляя следующее:

`OSError: [WinError 10038] Сделана попытка выполнить операцию на объекте, не являющемся сокетом`

Отладка не дала полезной для меня информации. Где я могу ошибаться? В понимании потоков? В MyUDPHandler?

---

Проблема скрывалась в методе *create_server*. Переписанный код:

```py
class Programm:
    ...
    def create_server(self):
        HOST, PORT = "localhost", 9999

        server = socketserver.UDPServer((HOST, PORT), MyUDPHandler)
        self.server_thread = threading.Thread(target=server.serve_forever)
        self.server_thread.start()
```

Comment: Как третий вариант: запускать с каждой стороны и сервер, и клиент.

Comment: Ещё идея: после установления соединения кидать оба потока в бесконечный цикл на приём данных. В нём сделать какой-нибудь if, который будет отвечать за выполнение отправки данных.

Comment: Сервер от клиента отличаются только фазой соединения. После того как соединение установлено это понятие размывается. Часть протоколов просто оговаривают кто в каком порядке отправляет и ждет данные. Но если необходима двусторонняя связь при которой любая из сторон в любой момент может что то посылать, то сокет надо проверять на наличие данных постоянно, в промежутках между другой работой. Это можно делать различными способами, но наиболее удобно использовать асинхронные методы. На сколько мне говорит гугл в питоне за это отвечает модуль syncio поизучайте его доку

Comment: Вообще на более низком уровне это делается с помощью функции select (или более эффективной poll), можете с ними попробовать (в гугле "python socket select"). syncio под капотом должна их использовать. И кстати отдельные потоки не особо то и нужны, при условии что основной и единственный поток не нагружен какой то вычислительной работой из за которой у него нет времени опрашивать сеть. Ну по крайней мере это в других языках так, подозреваю что в питоне то же самое

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Клиент-клиент соединение сложно в реализации, но возможно при использовании протоколов поверх udp.

Лучше же использовать соединение сервер-сервер с UDP. Ведь сокет сервер датаграм может отсылать сообщения на любой адрес.

Для опроса сервера есть готовые конструкции.

Синхронный сервер. https://docs.python.org/3/library/socketserver.html
. На каждое сообщение будет вызываться `handle` в котором можно читать сообщения. `server_thread = threading.Thread(target=server.serve_forever)` и Ваш сервер работает в отдельном потоке.

Асинхронный вариант чуть сложнее и требует запуска `asyncio.loop`
https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-protocol.html#udp-echo-server

Для графических приложений надо этот сервер запускать в отдельном процессе или запускаться на потоке графики через https://github.com/CabbageDevelopment/qasync или подобное.

Дергать poll/select - вариант, но это усложняет код.

Держи минимальный пример:

```
import socketserver
import sys
import threading

class MyUDPHandler(socketserver.BaseRequestHandler):

    def handle(self):
        data = self.request[0].strip()
        socket = self.request[1]
        peer, peer_port  = self.client_address # Узнаешь адрес вызывающей стороны
        print("\r{}:{} <".format(peer, peer_port))
        print(data.decode())

HOST, PORT = "0.0.0.0", int(sys.argv[1])
print('Serving at {}:{}'.format(HOST, PORT) )
server =  socketserver.UDPServer((HOST, PORT), MyUDPHandler) 
server_thread = threading.Thread(target=server.serve_forever)
server_thread.start()

sock = server.socket  

# Эта часть в графике будет не обязательной на одной стороне.
# Пира можно получить когда придет первый пакет. 
# Но в этой версии нужно ввести на обоих концах

peer, peer_port = input('Connect to:').split(':')
peer_port = int(peer_port)

while True: # основной цикл интерфейса
    sock.sendto(input('>').encode(), (peer, peer_port))
```

Запускаешь `python3 udpui.py 6667` и `python3 udpui.py 6667`. Потом вводи адрес обратной стороны и можно чатиться

Comment: Вижу в вашем ответе "соединение сервер-сервер", однако в документации по первой ссылке показывается лишь "соединение сервер-клиент". Но, насколько я понял, сервер тоже может выполнять _sendto_, поэтому это не фатально (как мне хочется верить).
Получается, обе программы у двух пользователей поднимают сервера, настроенные на приём информации, а отправляют информацию они обычной "функцией", без потоков?

Comment: Моих познаний хватает, чтобы понять, что строка `server_thread = threading.Thread(target=server.serve_forever)` "объявляет" поток, однако не запускает его. Тем не менее при попытке выполнить `server_thread.start()` на следующей строчке интерпретатор ругается, заявляя: `OSError: [WinError 10038] Сделана попытка выполнить операцию на объекте, не являющемся сокетом`. Где мог ошибиться пока что не вижу. Дополню вопрос через пару минут кодом и ошибкой.

Comment: @SergeyNaN да, всё так, sendto можно использовать в основном потоке

Comment: @SergeyNaN тут надо смотреть код)

Comment: Добавил "нужную" (по моему мнению) часть кода в вопрос, которая, собственно, и ломается.

Comment: Что-то тут намешанно сокет и сервер. Напишу пример

Comment: Заработало. Стоило лишь вынести код из-под `with ... as server:`.

Comment: За пример отдельное спасибо, сейчас ещё раз по нему пройдусь.

Comment: добавил коментарии

Comment: А можно прекратить выполнение потока "досрочно"? У меня программа закрывается, а процесс висит теперь. Я попытался `server_thread.join(x)` сделать, но что-то он мне не помог.

Решил проблему сохранением "ссылки" на `server` и вызовом `server.shutdown()` по ивенту.